# Change compiled css output location SASS with ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, sass

I'm building a mobile app using ionic framework and I would like to use Sass. I followed the Sass tutorial provided by the ionic team but I'm encounter a problem. I'm not very familiar with gulp, that's why I'm probably missing something.

I've changed my architecture folders and I've still an css folder that is created with sccs with ionicapp.css and ionic.app.min.css (www/css). **I would like to change the location (and generation) of this folder to www/assets/css**.  How can I do that ?

**My folder architecture is :**

```
| scss
    | ionic.app.scss
| www
    | app
        | app.route.js
        | app.controllers.js
            | My functionalities ..
    | assets
            | css
            | img
            | lib
                 | ionic
    | index.html
```

my scss/ionic.app.scss file :

```
/*
To customize the look and feel of Ionic, you can override the variables
in ionic's _variables.scss file.

For example, you might change some of the default colors:

$light:                           #fff !default;
$stable:                          #f8f8f8 !default;
$positive:                        #387ef5 !default;
$calm:                            #11c1f3 !default;
$balanced:                        #33cd5f !default;
$energized:                       #ffc900 !default;
$assertive:                       #ef473a !default;
$royal:                           #886aea !default;
$dark:                            #444 !default;
*/

// The path for our ionicons font files, relative to the built CSS in www/css

$ionicons-font-path: "../assets/lib/ionic/fonts" !default;

// Include all of Ionic
@import "www/assets/lib/ionic/scss/ionic";
```

And a part of my gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('default', ['sass']);

 gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
 gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
.pipe(sass())
.on('error', sass.logError)
.pipe(gulp.dest('./www/assets/css/'))
.pipe(minifyCss({
  keepSpecialComments: 0
}))
.pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./www/assets/css/'))
.on('end', done);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gulpfile.js should be something like:

```
gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
    gulp.src('./www/assets/scss/ionic.app.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .on('error', sass.logError)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/assets/css/'))
        .pipe(minifyCss({
            keepSpecialComments: 0
        }))
        .pipe(rename({
            extname: '.min.css'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/assets/css/'))
        .on('end', done);
});
```